# Cannot insert value NULL into column 'intGolferEventYearID', table does not allow nulls

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a dialog with a combobox listing the years an event was held.
Changing the year, changes the following list boxes
One list box 'called inEvent' shows all golfers the attended said event.
The other list box called 'available' that shows every golfer we have in our database that did not attend that years event

It has two buttons. One removes golfers from 'inEvent' and moves them to 'available'. This button works.
The other button does the opposite. It adds available golfers to the selected event year. But it gives me the error -
"The statement has been terminated. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'intGolferEventYearID', table 'dbo.TGolferEventYears'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Changing any line of code in VB results in a different error. So I think the error has to come from SQL itself which I don't know much about. Only other thing I can think of is the listbox is giving the wrong information.

```vb
Private Sub btnAddAuto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddAuto.Click

    Dim strInsert As String = ""
    Dim cmdInsert As OleDb.OleDbCommand ' used for our Select statement
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable ' table we will load from our reader
    Dim intRowsAffected As Integer

    ' open the DB
    OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer()

    ' Build the select statement
    strInsert = "INSERT INTO TGolferEventYears ( intGolferID, intEventYearID) Values (" & lstAvailable.SelectedValue & ", " & cboEvents.SelectedIndex + 1 & ")"

    ' Retrieve all the records 
    cmdInsert = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strInsert, m_conAdministrator)
    intRowsAffected = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ' close the database connection and reload the form so the changes are shown
    CloseDatabaseConnection()
    frmEventsGolfers_Load(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a NULL value into a field and in the table definition of your database, you have it set to not accept NULL values. You can change that table to accept nulls, or maybe you are accidently sending a null value when you want to send data. Actually, it looks like you have just forgotten to send the foreign key of 'intGolferEventYearID' in your insert statement. Make sure that is getting set.

Comment: The INSERT query is missing a required field. When you have corrected that, see about [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters). Use the [Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add) method to specify the fields values.

Comment: If this is SQL Server why do I see OleDb code?

Comment: @mary Custom DSN on the machine in question ?

Comment: @betelgeuce Good thought. I think DSN is not used in new code. Anyway, isn't that used with ODBC provider?

Comment: @Jimi You were closest to the correct answer. I was missing IDENTITY from my sql table.

Answer (score 0):

I separated the data access code from the user interface. This will make it easy to remove data access entirely from the Form if you later desire.

```vb
Private Sub MoveGolfer(GolfID As Integer, YearID As Integer)
    'If you keep your connections local you can be sure they are 
    'closed and disposed which is what the Using...End Using blocks do.
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TGolferEventYears ( intGolferID, intEventYearID) Values (@Golf, @Year;")
            'Always use parameters to protect against Sql injection
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Golf", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GolfID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = YearID
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim GolferID As Integer = CInt(lstAvailable.SelectedValue)
    Dim Year As Integer = cboEvents.SelectedIndex + 1
    Try
        MoveGolfer(GolferID, Year)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Catch a more specific exception and handle accordingly
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't really understand SQL I didn't realize my PK didn't have the IDENTITY tag added in the table. Adding this fixed my issue.

Here is the code I added

```
        Dim strSelect As String
        Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand            
        Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Dim intNextHighestRecordID As 

        strSelect = "SELECT MAX(intDealerAutos) + 1 AS intNextHighestRecordID " &
                        " FROM TDealerAutos"

        'Excute command
        cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
        drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

        'Read result( highest ID )
        drSourceTable.Read()

        'Null? (Empty Table)
        If drSourceTable.IsDBNull(0) = True Then
            'Yes, start numbering at 1
            intNextHighestRecordID = 1
        Else
            'No, get the next highest ID
            intNextHighestRecordID = CInt(drSourceTable.Item(0))
        End If

        'Build the select statement
        strInsert = "INSERT INTO TDealerAutos ( intDealerAutos, intDealerID, intAutoID)" &
                    "Values (" & intNextHighestRecordID & ", " & cboDealers.SelectedValue & ", " & lstAvailable.SelectedValue & ")"
```